# Save or Retrieve the data in Rstudio

Tags: r, rstudio, data-retrieval

Sir,i am a student, learning R,I have a question about how to store data in R, or how to retrieve data that has been erased.

Answer (score 1):

Sir,

Using RStudio is not much different than using, say, Word or Notepad, but with some differences.
First the similarities:

If *you* do not *save* your Rscript or data, it might not be available after you restart RStudio or if you overwrite/erase your data.

The advantage of using R and Rstudio is that you can *script* how you load and manipulate your data, hence recreate the data. *If* you use a script and do not rely only on the console (interactive) part.

For the differences, Rstudio can be set to save your current workspace. This is were all data and variables loaded reside. To change the settings, go to "Tools" --> "Global options" and you should see the options as depicted below.

However, if you erase your data by overwriting with other values or using the command `unset`, the data is lost. Your only recourse is to retrace how it was loaded/modified, using either your script or going through the "history".

[image: RStudio global options]

**For saving data**, see e.g. http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/saving-data-into-r-data-format-rds-and-rdata. Note the difference between `save` and `saveRDS` where the former saves data with their variable names, whereas `saveRDS` saves the data without and must be loaded into a variable.